# Is CLLocationManager can work with external GPS in MAC

Tags: macos, cocoa, gps, cllocationmanager

Is CLLocationManager can work with external GPS in MAC?

After ask google for a while I can't find anything.

If it can't, then how can I get location from external GPS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From external GPS you get location by reading either

- The NMEA Protocoll from the (virtual) COM port the GPS device is connected to (usually virtual COM via USB). All GPS chips support the NMEA protcoll.
- or the chips propriertary binary protocoll.

These deleivers all data you need, you dont need the CLLLocationManager anymore.

Comment: my goal is to make sure that CLLocationManager work with external gps or not. Can you confirm me about this ,and thank for your answer this is very helpful.

Comment: No it does not work with external GPS. CLLocationManager is an API for internl GPS. So better write your own Location wrapper, forward CLLocationMAnager to your LocationManager when using internal GPS, and when using extnernal GPS parse the NMEA sentences and forwyard them to your LocationManager.